# Proving an example doesn't violate the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, normal-distribution, intuition

I just worked through the following example from Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance*.

> For each positive integer $n$, define $f_n$ to be the normal density
> with mean $0$ and variance $n$, i.e.,
>
> $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2n}}\text{.}$$

He defines $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$. Then he poses the problem

> (iii) Note that
>
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int _{-\infty} ^{\infty} f_n(x)\, dx \neq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx\text{.}$$
>
> Explain why this does not violate the Monotone Convergence Theorem,
> Theorem 1.4.5.

It's easy to see that these functions aren't monotonically decreasing, so the assumptions for the Monotone Convergence Theorem aren't satisfied. I now want to understand why this example does not violate the Dominated Convergence Theorem. I believe that it suffices to show that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x) \, dx \nless \infty \text{.}$$

I have two questions about this.

1. Can you confirm, yes or no, that the above (essentially) proves the $f_n$ do not satisfy the assumption of the Dominated Convergence Theorem?
2. Do you have an explanation for why the above display is true? A proof is preferable, the details aren't important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $x>1$. $\sup_n f_n(x)\geq f_{[x^{2}]}(x)$ where $[,]$ is the greatest integer function. $f_{[x^{2}]}(x) \geq \frac  1 {(2\pi)^{1/2} |x|}e^{-x^{2}/2[x^{2}]}$. Note that  $x^{2}/[x^{2}] \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$. Conclude that $\int_0^{\infty} \sup_n f_n(x)dx=\infty$.